# Why is apt-get downloads so slow

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I am new to Ubuntu and using 14.04.2.  I am finding apt-get downloads extremely slow.  Most are coming from security.ubuntu.com or us.archive.ubuntu.com.  I am only getting download speeds from 5 to 12 kB/s which is only 2% of my network speed.  And for pkgs with dependent pkgs, the reconnect for each new package often takes several minutes.  Just doing apt-get upgrade took around 10 hours.  Is this normal?  Are the servers slow or so busy?  I found yum with RedHat much faster.

Comment: I used Debian, and have not seen these problems. If it is the servers, then changing to a more local mirror may help: find out how to edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` or change it using a graphical package manager (`synaptic` has a tool to do this, in settings/repositories menu).

Comment: happened today, download speeds dropped to 125Bps (no, the k is not missing). Resetting the router fixed it for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with the sources. Go to

**System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Download from -> Select best server**

For more additional details, refer [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156650/apt-get-update-very-slow-stuck-at-waiting-for-headers) thread.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I had set a [bandwidth limit](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/apt/apt-transport-http.1.en.html#Connection_Configuration:%7E:text=The%20used%20bandwidth,per%20second.) in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`:

```
// Use apt bandwidth limit feature, this example limits the download
// speed to 70kb/sec
Acquire::http::Dl-Limit "70";
```

(I wasn't expecting this to affect my "attended upgrades" also..)

As soon as I commented out this line, `apt install` went much faster.

Answer (score 4):

The apt-fast package can be installed in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu by adding the apt-fast/stable PPA to your software sources and installing it using these commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apt-fast/stable 
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y install apt-fast
```

During the apt-fast installation process, you will be prompted to perform some package configuration. After successfully installing apt-fast, simply use it the same way you run apt or apt-get.

Comment: I noticed that your PPA isn't supported past Ubuntu 16.04, so I substituted the more up-to-date ppa:apt-fast/stable. You can rollback my edit if you want to by clicking the rollback link [here](https://superuser.com/posts/1416864/revisions).

Comment: Interesting solution, it's a shame that it requires to run apt-get update which is the broken thing that we are attempting to fix.

Comment: @matteo I don't think you do. if you use `-u` on `add-apt-repository`, so it all becomes

`sudo add-apt-repository -u ppa:apt-fast/stable && sudo apt -y install apt-fast`

Answer (score 2):

This is added late, current os 20.04 focal, had a few weeks of having to wait 3 or more minutes at the end of `apt-get update` for some unknown cause. I struggled with trying to find a fix via search engine. Somehow I came across an article about snap and complaint that it took too much time.

I found this at https://cialu.net/a-better-ubuntu-linux-without-the-crappy-snap/

I ran the following:

```
$ sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd gnome-software-plugin-snap
```

I was worried about all the removals, but apt-get update runs like it used to.
Question: Is snap a cloud based thing? ( that would explain the time delay )

Answer (score -1):

For me a fake sd card from amazon was the problem... Was supposed to be 64Gb but was actually 4GB. TBF amazon accepted return. Having popped to Argos and bought a 64GB card for 10 quid its working fine and ubuntu now runs acceptably.